# Nightmare.js and IE compatibility mode

Tags: nightmare

I can't find any info on this, mostly because once i type a google search with "nightmare" and "IE" on the same sentence, you know...

Is there a way to run nightmare.js as on IE compatibility mode ?

Comment: hm, i just found http://triflejs.org/ , ill try this

Comment: havn't tried triffle.org yet tho. using Selenium and so far so perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nightmare.js is based on Electron.js based on Chromium.
So there are no IE compatible API.